# Parse “math340-05 =?UTF-8?B?4oCTIEF1ZmdhYmUgNS4x?=”

Tags: python

I want to extract the subject from an email which is stored in an `.eml` file using Python 3:

The subject line from the file is the following:

```
Subject: math340-05 =?UTF-8?B?4oCTIEF1ZmdhYmUgNS4x?=
```

I try to parse the name using the `email` module, but it returns the string as is:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    m = email.message_from_file(f)

print(m["Subject"])
```

How can I decode that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to us the `email.header`  module:

```
import email, email.header
m = email.message_from_string("Subject: math340-05 =?UTF-8?B?4oCTIEF1ZmdhYmUgNS4x?=")
raw_header = email.header.decode_header(m["Subject"])
header = email.header.make_header(raw_header)
print(str(header))
# or for py2: print(unicode(header))
```

will give you:

```
math340-05 – Aufgabe 5.1
```